# List with if - plus and minus

Tags: prolog

I should create a list with integer.It should be ziga_arnitika(L,ML).Which take L list (+) integer and will return the list ML only (-) integer the even numbers of list L.
Warning:The X mod Y  calculates   X:Y.

```
Example: ziga_arnitika([3,6,-18,2,9,36,31,-40,25,-12,-5,-15,1],ML).
ML =[-18,-40,-12]
```

i know for example with not list to use if but not with lists,what i did is..:

```
something(12) :-
write('Go to L).
something(10) :-
write('Go to Ml).
something(other) :-
Go is other -10,
format('Go to list ~w',[ML]).
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute a list with elements satisfying some properties from a given list. Lists in Prolog have a very simple representation. The empty list is represent by `[]`. A non-empty list is a sequence of elements separated by a comma. E.g. `[1,2,3]`. Prolog also provides handy notation to split a list between its head (or first element) and its tail (a list with the remaining arguments):

```
?- [1,2,3] = [Head| Tail].
Head = 1,
Tail = [2, 3].
```

Walking a list (from its first element to its last element) can be done easily using a simple recursive predicate. The trivial case is when a list is empty:

```
walk([]).
```

If a list is not empty, we move to the list tail:

```
walk([Head| Tail]) :- walk(Tail).
```

However, if you try this predicate definition in virtually any Prolog system, it will warn you that `Head` is a *singleton variable*. That means that the variable appears once in a predicate clause. You can solve the warning by replacing the variable `Head` with an *anonymous variable* (which we can interpret as "don't care" variable). Thus, currently we have:

```
walk([]).
walk([_| Tail]) :- walk(Tail).
```

We can try it with our example list:

```
?- walk([1,2,3]).
true.
```

Prolog being a *relational* language, what happens if we call the `walk/1` predicate with a variable instead?

```
?- walk(List).
List = [] ;
List = [_4594] ;
List = [_4594, _4600] ;
List = [_4594, _4600, _4606]
...
```

Now back to the original problem: constructing a list from elements of other list. We want to process each element of the input list and, if it satisfies some property, adding it to the output list. We need two arguments. The simple case (or *base* case) is again when the input list is empty:

```
process([], []).
```

The general case (or *recursive* case) will be:

```
process([Head| Tail], [Head| Tail2]) :-
    property(Head),
    process(Tail, Tail2).
```

assuming a predicate `property/1` that is true when its argument satisfies some property. In your case, being a even, negative integer. But not all elements will satisfy the property. To handle that case, we need a third clause that will skip an element that doesn't satisfy the property:

```
 process([Head| Tail], List) :-
    \+ property(Head),
    process(Tail, List).
```

The `\+/1` predicate is Prolog standard *negation* predicate: it's true when its argument is false.

Let's try our `process/2` predicate it by defining a `property/1` predicate that is true if the argument is the integer zero:

```
property(0).
```

A sample call would then be:

```
?- process([1,0,2,0,0,3,4,5], List).
List = [0, 0, 0] ;
false
```

We have successfully written a predicate that extracts all the zeros from a list. Note that our query have a single *solution*. If we type a `;` to ask for the next solution at the prompt, the Prolog top-level interpreter will tell us that there are no more solutions (the exact printout depends on the chosen Prolog system; some will print e.g. `no` instead of `false`but the meaning is the same).

Can you now solve your original question by defining a suitable `property/1` predicate?

**Update**

You can combine the two recursive clauses in one by writing for example:

```
process([Head| Tail], List) :-
    (   % condition
        property(Head) ->
        % then
        List = [Head| Tail2],
        process(Tail, Tail2)
    ;   % else
        process(Tail, List)
    ).
```

In this case, we use the Prolog standard if-then-else *control construct*. Note, however, that this construct does an implicit *cut* in the condition. I.e. we only take the first solution for the `property/1` predicate and discard any other potential solutions. The use of this control construct also prevents using the `process/2` predicate in *reverse* (e.g. calling it with an unbound first argument and a bound second argument) or using it to *generate* pairs of terms that satisfy the relation (e.g. calling it with both arguments unbound). These issues may or may not be significant depending on the property that you're using to filter the list and on the details of the practical problem that you're solving. More sophisticated alternatives are possible but out of scope for this introductory answer.

Comment: It is very well written and understandable i can confess.Until now i know it all of them.But i should have use if statement on the list,there i have the issue.How can i do with if -statement because i must split as you refered

Comment: if you could make an answer similar example using > or <